# How to drop 500 pins at once on a MapView

Tags: ios, swift

I have around 500 pins I would like to display on a MKMapView.

However, when I call `mapView.addAnnotations(places)` (`places` being an array of MKAnnotation objects), the pins slowly drop one by one.

I would like to either :

- drop all pins at once at load
- cancel the drop animation altogether

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set `animatesDrop` property of your `MKAnnotationViews` to `NO(false)`

Comment: Thanks. If it can help others, this must be done in the `mapView:viewForAnnotation:` delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

By setting animation property to No will drop all the Pins at once on the MapView.

```
MKAnnotationView *annotationView =[[MKAnnotationView alloc]init];
annotationView.animatesDrop=FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to implement your own drop animation in the didAddAnnotationViews delegate method. You should also set animatesDrop to NO to avoid a possible double animation.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)annotationViews
{
    NSTimeInterval delayInterval = 0;

   for (MKAnnotationView *annView in annotationViews)
   {
       CGRect endFrame = annView.frame;

       annView.frame = CGRectOffset(endFrame, 0, -500);

       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.125 
                          delay:delayInterval
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                     animations:^{ annView.frame = endFrame; } 
                     completion:NULL];

       delayInterval += 0.0625;
    }
}
```